# Python regex special characters with inputed search strings

Tags: python, regex, search, text-files

Thanks to the help of some most excellent members on here I have learned a lot about regular expressions and have this semi-working. I need to add the characters: " , () : ; - . ? to my regex search. The problem is I am passing inputed search strings to the regex and do not know how to get this to work.

Here is the code:

```
text = open_file.read()

grammarList = raw_input("Enter your grammar string: ");
tags = grammarList.split("^")
tags_pattern = r"\b" + r"\s+".join(r"(\w+)/{0}".format(tag) for tag in tags) + r"\b" 
# gives you r"\b(\w+)/NNP\s+(\w+)/CC\s+(\w+)/NNP\b"

from re import findall
start_position = 0

for poem in poemList:
    start_position = text.find('<' + poem + '>', start_position)
    end_position = text.find('</' + poem + '>', start_position)

    searchtext = text [start_position:end_position]
    poemname = poem
    for oldname, newname in poemtitleswapList.items():
        poemname = poemname.replace(oldname, newname)
    print poemname
    print(findall(tags_pattern, searchtext))
    print "\n"
```

and here is a sample of the text file:

```
To/TO
emotion/NN
for/IN
all/DT
there/EX
is/VBZ
in/IN
it/PRP
,/,
```

It works great for everything but commas, round brackets, periods, semi-colons, question marks, colons, dashes and quotation marks. I need it to be able to find these things too. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: use an XML parser to extract `searchtext` from text instead of `text.find` if `text` contains XML.

Comment: thanks sebastion, I should have been more specific. I am still learning I apologize.  it searches for the capital letters or symbol on the right side of the forward slash. SO if I type in NN^IN^DT it matches all the times those occur in sequence in the text file on the right of the slash. I need to be able to include those other types of characters so I can run a search VBZ^IN^PRP^,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could escape characters that has special meaning in a regex using `re.escape(tag)`. To allow non-word characters on the left you could replace `\w+/` by `[^/]+/`:

```
pattern = r'\s+'.join(r"^([^/]+)/{0}".format(re.escape(tag)) for tag in tags)
print re.findall(pattern, searchtext, re.M)
```

[Output](http://ideone.com/5BTvI)

```
[('is', 'in', 'it', ',')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this just doesn't work. It is outputting crazy strings.  I am search for an undetermined length of tags on the right of the slash and it is supposed to return the corresponding words on the right. If I enter TO^NN^IN it searches a huge text file and returns everytime it finds those 3 tags in that sequence and then returns each corresponding word on the left of the tag.  It works right now but won't return an punctuation.

Comment: @English Grad: It does work. Click on [the above link](http://ideone.com/5BTvI). You could try it with your sample (click on `upload with new input` on the ideone page).

Comment: @English Grad: the first line should be a grammar string, see [#4 output](http://ideone.com/5BTvI#li_4BLWj).